# Combining getOOBPreds with nested resampling and parameter tuning

Tags: r, random-forest, mlr

In the package `R::mlr` I read from [the tutorial that the `getOOBPreds` function that I can access the out-of-bag predictions from say a random forest model](http://mlr-org.github.io/mlr/articles/out_of_bag_predictions.html), but I cannot figure out how to use this in a nested resampling procedure designed to tune hyperparameters.

I understand that the inner loop shoud be somehow

Thanks for sharing insights / hints !

I tried as inner loop:

```
makeTuneWrapper(lrnr,
  resampling = "oob",
  par.set = params,
  control = ctrl,
  show.info = TRUE,
  measures =  list(logloss, multiclass.brier,
timetrain))
```

... but the value `"oob"` for parameter resampling is not valid.

tentative MRE:

```
library(mlr)

# Task
tsk = iris.task
# Learner
lrnr <- makeLearner("classif.randomForestSRC", predict.type = "prob")
# Hyperparameters
params <- makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("mtry",lower = 2,upper = 10),
                   makeIntegerParam("nodesize",lower = 1,upper = 100),
                   makeIntegerParam("nsplit",lower = 1,upper = 20))
# Validation strategy
rdesc_inner_oob <- makeResampleDesc("oob")  # FAILS
ctrl <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 10L)
tuning_lrnr = makeTuneWrapper(lrnr,
                   # resampling = oob,        # ALSO WRONG
                   resampling = rdesc_inner_oob,
                   par.set = params,
                   control = ctrl,
                   measures =  list(logloss, multiclass.brier, timetrain))

outer = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 3)
r = resample(learner  = tuning_lrnr,
           task       = tsk,
           resampling = outer,
           extract    = getOOBPreds,
           show.info  = TRUE,
           measures   = list(multiclass.brier))
```

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, this is currently not supported in mlr. You can really only get the out-of-bag predictions in a separate step.

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff. Btw: I found the package [tuneR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tuneRanger/index.html). It is tuninf RFs by optimizing a Brier score on oob obs.